# Eclipse Formatter and Checkstyle checks. Eclipse Formatter breaks on comments

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, checkstyle

I want to check my Eclipse-formatted Java-code with Checkstyle on the CI system. However I am facing some troubles since Eclipse seems to ignore //comments. Here are more details:

On the Eclipse-side I made a setting that the curly of a control statement should be followed by a whitespace (Formatter -> WhiteSpace->Control Statements->Blocks)
In Checkstyle I activated the same rule that a curly should have whitespace before and afterwards.

However this seems to break with the following pattern:

```
if(condition) {//comment
    doStuff();
}//endOfIf
```

If I put a line comment directly after the curly the Eclipse Formatter doesn't put a whitespace around and so CheckStyle gives me a warning.

I think Checkstyle is right and Eclipse handles this wrong. How can I change the behaviour in Eclipse so that he handles the things right?